# value cannot be null. parameter name encoder MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using Two separate buttons to rotate the image and save the image. Somehow the rotation is working. But the save(Update) is not working. I tried to find the problem, but I couldn't.

The error is "value cannot be null. parameter name encoder".
My best guess is that RotateFlip is somehow effecting the picture Box.

Regards

This is my code,

```
private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBoxProfile.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBoxProfile.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                pictureBoxProfile.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select an Image");
            }
        }


private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtShortName.Text == "" || txtPhoneNumberM.Text == "" || txtFullName.Text == "" || gender.Text == "" || richTextBoxAddress.Text == "" || txtPhoneNumberH.Text == "" || status.Text == "" || pictureBoxProfile.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty fields are detected!. Please fill up all fields");
                return;
            }

            try
            {

                con.Open();                

                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE customer SET mr_mrs = @mr_mrs, short_name = @short_name, full_name = @full_name, nic_number = @nic_number, gender = @gender, address = @address, phone_no_home = @phone_no_home, phone_no_mobile = @phone_no_mobile, image = @image, status = @status, type = @type, nic_frnt = @nic_frnt, nic_back = @nic_back WHERE (nic_number=@nic_number)", con);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBoxProfile.Image.Save(ms, pictureBoxProfile.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] img = ms.ToArray();

                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms2, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] img2 = ms2.ToArray();

                MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox3.Image.Save(ms3, pictureBox3.Image.RawFormat);
                byte[] img3 = ms3.ToArray();

                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mr_mrs", mr_mrs.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@short_name", txtShortName.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", txtFullName.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nic_number", textBox1.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", richTextBoxAddress.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_no_home", txtPhoneNumberH.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_no_mobile", txtPhoneNumberM.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", img);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", comboBox1.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nic_frnt", img2);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nic_back", img3);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Customer updated succesfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Close();
                con.Close();
                ClearData();
            }
            catch (MySqlException x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess one of your columns is set to `NOT NULL`, but you try to update it to `NULL`

Comment: you mean in Mysql Database?

Comment: Yep, that's what I suspect

Comment: Nope. Mysql Database NULL Values are allowed

Comment: Just a wild guess: Try changing your parameter names from "@varname" to "?varname". Maybe you need to use the question mark in your update statement only: `MySqlCommand("Update ... Set colName = ?varName` but use the varName without the question mark when adding the param: `AddwithValue( "varName", variable )`

Comment: I have changed just now, But still not working

Comment: Have you tried answer by @EsnEzz, it should work, avoid using `Image.RawFormat` while saving, it should be some specific format, like `Jpeg`, `Bmp` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Image.Save method.
Instead of:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
```

Try this:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imageformat.Jpeg);
```